# systemd - service stops again right after starting up - podman

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, podman

I created an unit file, with the following lines to start-up a podman container. Unfortunately, right after starting up, `journalctl -xe` tells me service not needed, shutting down, service shuts down. `podman ps --all` says `exited (0)`, hence, it is a regular stop.

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for auto-start the Podman NGINX Container
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root

ExecStart=podman start nginx
ExecStop=podman stop nginx

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried also some variants with `StopWhenUnneeded=false`, which made no difference.

System is RedHat8. The official [RedHat-description](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/running_containers_as_systemd_services_with_podman) to solve this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Podman command for creating a systemd service unit file

`podman generate systemd --name --new nginx`.

See  the [**podman generate systemd** man page](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-generate-systemd.1.html).

Here is an example:

```
[root@asus ~]# podman create --name nginx -p 80:80 docker.io/library/nginx
7844db33bf66233f71c74ce0d43e590a8478b087198dfc276477baaf20a9b503
[root@asus ~]# podman generate systemd --name --new nginx > /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service
[root@asus ~]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@asus ~]# systemctl start nginx.service
[root@asus ~]# curl localhost:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
[root@asus ~]# podman --version
podman version 3.4.4
[root@asus ~]# cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)
[root@asus ~]#
```

Comment: A colleague told me that finally (after I forgot about my question). But it's always usefull to have questions answered here => +1